# A way to know if the word contain a "e muet" without relying on the prononciation

Tags: prononciation, orthographe

As a **deaf** person and native french speaker, **I'd like to know if there's a way to know if a word contain a "*e* muet" without relying on the pronunciation.**

In order to able to place the accent based on the grammar rule that you can find [here](https://www.francaisfacile.com/exercices/exercice-francais-2/exercice-francais-8789.php) in french, I have to know if the next syllable contain a "*e* muet" but as I said I'm deaf, thus not able to easily know if the *e* is pronounced.

For example, let's take *mystère* and *règle*.

> **Quand doit on mettre un accent ?**
>   Pour le savoir, il faut couper le mot par syllabe :
>   Si la syllabe contenant le son « é/è » se termine par une consonne, on ne met pas d'accent.
>   Sinon, on met un accent.

If we apply the rule we can say that for both example it requires an accent but we don't know which one.

> **Accent aigu « é » ou accent grave « è » ?**
>   Observez la syllabe suivante (à droite) :
>   Si elle contient un « e » muet, on met un accent grave « è ».
>   Sinon, on met un accent aigu « é ».

And here comes the problem, I'm totally unable to know if *mystèr**e*** and *règl**e*** is a "*e* muet" or not.

Comment: A word-final <e> or <es> is always a "e muet", unless the word is monosyllabic, in which cas <es> represent the same sound as <è> (as in *les*, *des*) but <e> is still a "e muet" (as in *de*)

Comment: Il est **à mon opinion** un peu risqué de chercher à deviner l'accentuation d'un mot à la présence ou non d'un e muet. Ce d'autant qu'il existe d'autres accents possibles. Tu prends l'exemple de **mystère** OK mais prenons **mystérieux** qu'est ce qui peut de dire qu'il y a un accent aigu ? La seule façon, de le savoir c'est de l'avoir ainsi appris... Sans compter les exceptions nombreuses (avènement mais événement)... (difficultés réduites par la réforme de 1970 encore peu appliquée.) L'histoire de l'accent grave dépendant d'un e muet n'est, à mon opinion, utile que dans la conjugaison.

Answer (score 2):

The International Phonetic Alphabet describes how words are pronounced in physiological terms and is not subject to varied accents, etc. If you use a tool that translates French into IPA (e.g a dictionary) and learn to read IPA (e.g. here http://dialectblog.com/the-international-phonetic-alphabet/ipa-tutorial/lesson-1/) you should be able to produce correct pronunciation just from reading. Standard pronunciation, that is - obviously e muet may appear in different places depending on someone's accent.